# How to set Sensitivity to "true" in LpSolve

Tags: java, linear-algebra, lpsolve

I'm looking to enable sensitivity in LpSolve (http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/sensitivity.htm).

The docs indicate that you enable sensitivity by passing -S4 to the command line. In R, you can pass compute.sens=true in the lpsolve() function call.

However, I'm using the Java API, and I see no such option for setting it.

I do see a setSense(boolean maximize) function. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also struggling with LPSolve, but I did find some useful code, that included the code line

```
lp.setSense(true);
```

`lp` is the name of the var assigned to the *makeLP* command.

I however do not know how to set the degree as stated in the docs...

I hope this answers your question.